How long do spikes from my Sorcerer's Wild Magic ability last?
Sometimes my Sorcerer's Wild Magic ability will spawn spikes around me that damages anyone that walks through them.
But how long do the spikes from Wild Magic last?

[Comments removed] - Hey all, let's focus on the question, not on the validity of comments.  Remember that comments are for requesting clarification, constructive criticism, or to add relevant but minor information or context. If you want to continue this discussion, move it to [chat] or [meta]

There's two Spike Growth abilities, I'm not sure which you're referring to:
The Wild Magic Barbarian's ability is called Wild Magic: Vine Growth. It lasts 10 turns, and it follows you around.
The Wild Magic Sorcerer's ability is called Wild Magic: Spike Growth. It lasts 3 turns.

Does it actually follow you around? I've never played as a Wild Mage in BG3 before, but that seems unlikely, and I can't find it back on the page (or elsewhere, after a quick search).

@Joachim instead of a fixed location as with the normal spell (because you can't choose a target location) you yourself are the target and as you move the effect moves with you.

Googling "wild magic spawn spikes" gives me Wild Magic: Spike Growth as the first result, which is said to last for 3 turns.
